# what is the soure that rav use to say by shiduchim How much do you give your son?

Tags: sources-mekorot, engagement-shidduch

what is the original source of

Rav, used the following formula: "How much do you give your son? So much and so much. How much do you give your daughter? So much and so much.

from http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/480506/jewish/Agreement-to-Marry.htm

Comment: -1 someone loves me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for Moed Katan 18b / Ketubbot 102b / Kiddushin 9b (translation from Soncino):

> אמר רב גידל אמר רב כמה אתה נותן לבנך כך וכך לבתך כך וכך עמדו וקדשו קנו
>   R. Giddal has laid down in the name of Rab: [If one man said to another,] "How much are you giving to your son?" [and the other replied,] "Such and such a sun,", and [when the other asks,] "How much are you giving to your daughter?" [the first replies,] "Such and such a sum", [and on the basis of this talk] betrothal was effected, kinyan is deemed to have been executed